# Прошлый, прошедший или этот месяц?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Сегодня 9 марта. Как правильно сказать про последний ноябрь? *Прошедший ноябрь? Этот ноябрь (хоть уже и следующий календарный год)? Прошлый ноябрь?*

Вопрос возник, именно когда я увидел наименование *прошлый ноябрь.* Разве так правильно?

Буду благодарен за развёрнутый ответ, в том числе и с какими-то другими примерами кроме описанного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошлый ноябрь, прошедший ноябрь - все годится. Вообще "прошлый" и "прошедший" при подобном календарном употреблении - почти полные синонимы. Честно говоря даже не понимаю, что вас смущает и каких примеров вам надобно.

Но попробую: *в прошлом веке* (сейчас это 20-й), *в прошлый понедельник* (вот тут может возникнуть непонимание, если дело происходит, скажем, в пятницу, но все равно это больше воспринимается как понедельник прошлой недели, а "прошедший" будет скорее всего означать тот, который на этой неделе), даже *прошлым утром*. Все это нормально и более или менее понятно.

"Этот ноябрь" - двусмысленно, скорее может относиться к ноябрю будущему.

*Хотел было написать, что вот у англичан все строго и понятно, но сообразил, что только запутаю, ибо там понятно для тех, кто вжился в эту схему относительного времени (например, "last night", "this night", "tonight", "next night" строго соответствует времени на момент повествования), а для носителя русского может это похлеще всех последних и последующих ноябрей. Так что не заморачивыайтесь.*

Comment: Спасибо большое!! В вашем примере с понедельником я скажу *в этот понедельник,* раз это допустимо. Для меня так естественнее. Наверно, действительно, по аналогии с английским. Как я говорил, например, будучи школьником, лет двадцать назад, даже не помню. А вообще очень любопытно находить свои какие-то старые записи. ;)

Answer (score 2):

В таких выражениях нужно учитывать *относительный* характер ссылки на месяц. В ситуации 9 марта о прошедшем месяце ноябре лучше сказать "**в ноябре прошлого года**", а о ноябре текущего года - просто "**в ноябре**".  Ситуация, в которой уместно выражение "**в прошлом ноябре**" возможна, но встречается редко: можно представить себе, что говорится это в ноябре, и речь идёт о ежегодном событии, всегда намечаемом на ноябрь. В остальных случаях такое выражение малоупотребительно (если не просторечие, то плохой стиль); с днями недели - иначе: выражение "*в прошлый понедельник*", сказанное в любой день недели, вполне обычно и означает "*в понедельник прошлой недели*". Поэтому не стоит ориентироваться на аналогии с неделями, годами и т. п.

О выражениях "**прошлый, прошедший, этот**" применительно к месяцу. "Прошлый" означает "предыдущий, предшествующий" календарный месяц. "Прошедший" отличается тем, что так можно сослаться и на месяц, который формально ещё не закончился. Поэтому полными синонимами эти слова не являются. "Этот" применимо к текущему "месяцу", но к названию месяца его уместно относить только в особых случаях, когда время между регламентированными событиями условно оценивается напр. "от ноября до ноября" (см. выше о "прошлом ноябре"). Обычно же временные интервалы измеряются месяцами, а не "ноябрями", поэтому при ссылке на ноябрь текущего года правильно "*в ноябре этого года*" или просто "*в ноябре*" (если текущий год следует из контекста).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Вчера забыл принять ответ, теперь даже не знаю, какой выбрать.)

Comment: *"Прошедший" отличается тем, что так можно сослаться и на месяц, который формально ещё не закончился.* Разве? Я бы так не сказал...

Comment: Представьте себе, что кто-то в конце месяца, оценивая какие-либо особенные для этого месяца события, достижения, климатические аномалии и т. п., пытается сослаться на этот самый месяц (год) в присутствии людей, которые в этом месяце больше не встретятся (больше не будут совместно его проводить). Осталось два-три календарных дня, но для того, чтобы назвать этот месяц "прошедшим", такая формальность не имеет значения: для присутствующих он был наполнен тем, о чём говорится. А вот "прошлым" в той же ситуации назвать этот месяц невозможно: это будет ссылка на предшествующий ему месяц.

Comment: И ещё такая же ситуация возможна в случае, когда речь идёт о совместно проведённом месяце, но не в "календарном" смысле (напр. с середины одного месяца до середины другого). "Прошедший месяц" в подобных случаях отсчитывается от начала меропрития или от какого-то события и означает прошествие месячного временного интервала. "Прошлый" же - всегда указание на другой календарный месяц.